# No Follow Links

Tags: support, profile-page, accounts, external-links

My reputation is more than 2000 on Stack Overflow, but still, my links are [nofollow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow).

I thought that above 2000 points the nofollow restriction was to be removed.

I am giving a lot to the community, but sometimes I wish that Stack Overflow should link back to my detailed articles written on my website.

A few of my answers with no-follow links:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61469462/5701085

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62404213/5701085

Comment: In some of your posts you forgot to disclaim you were the author of the linked article.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that that was a [privilege you could earn?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: Ok thanks i will put the disclaimer, can you give me any example?

Comment: Personally, I believe it's fine if every single external link on the site is decorated with `rel="nofollow"`. User generated content can very easily be abused for SEO purposes.

Comment: @Daedalus [From Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/55843/153008)

Comment: But that's only on the "website link" (as in, the profile). Not on posts, comments, etc.

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah, but that's for the user profile.  Unless I am mistaken, this MSO post is not about the user profile, but general posts.

Comment: Even in my about section, I have no-follow link of my website
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5701085/asad-ali-choudhry?tab=profile

Comment: @AsadAliChoudhry Where did you get the idea that that privilege is applied in a non-profile manner?

Answer (score 6):

At 2000 rep, `rel=nofollow` is removed from the "website" link in your profile.

This one:

> [image]

As you can see in the markup, that link does not include `rel="nofollow"`:

[image]

But as Jeff says [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55842/no-follow-attribute-set-in-user-profile-website-link-why/55843#55843), `nofollow` is applied to every other link:

> However, we do nofollow all other links in the profile as a matter of course, the same way we do in posts, comments, etc.

User generated content is very often gamed for SEO purposes, so this practice makes perfect sense.

Comment: Nice info, but there is still a confusion. Here is my another answer. That should be no-follow according to your rule, but unexpectedly from that no-follow is removed.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60322365/5701085

Comment: Huh. That's weird. I hope that's a bug, and that it gets fixed soon.

Comment: haha I thought the other was the bug.

Comment: One reason can be that i have made a disclaimer that it's my article. what do you say?

Comment: No, all external links should have `rel=nofollow`. The site should not be used as a SEO farm.

Comment: Ok got it. so 2000 reputation doesn't really matter, except the profile page.

Comment: Probably just a glitch in the renderer. Submitted an edit and the `rel=nofollow` has been applied correctly.